# Marketing Cloud API as Entry Event - Send transaction email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketingcloudapi

I have a very simple use case where I need to send a transactional email via journey. I used API as an entry event and hit the endpoint. I got the success and a record is created in the underlying data extension which I connect when creating an entry source.

I initially thought that once the record is created in the data extension my next steps like waiting for 1 min and then sending an email will be automatically executed but I guess that is not the case.
Can anyone guide me what could be the next steps in order to execute the next steps in the journey like sending the transactional email? Thanks

Comment: Hi @gautam , can you please confirm did you use journey builder API event - '/interaction/v1/events'.? If yes, can you please add your API request in the question? So that it will be easy for others to troubleshoot.

Comment: I used the below code as API event of journey and I got the success. {
    "ContactKey": "ID601",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-",
    "Data": {
        "SubscriberKey": "",
        "EmailAddress": "",
        "FirstName": "",
        "LastName": "",
        "Barcode": "",
  "Sender": "",
  "Address": "",
  "DeliveryDate": ""
}
}Now record is created in de underlying the API event of journey. My initial understanding was that the next steps in the journey like email send should be automatically initiated but actually not.Can you help how to trigger the next steps  of journey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DE should not be associated with any template

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are on the right direction. If you try to call out the journey entry event API then it will insert a record in data extension and it will also send out a real time email.

**My findings on your issue:**

- Check if its entering into the journey by clicking on View events in journey.

  [image]
- Check if you are using any ampscript in journey builder emails. Sometimes if you don't pass the values or column names are different then the emails won't send.
- Make sure you have a field email address with email address data type in the send able data extension.
- Just check whether if you have provided a valid email address.

**Please find the below steps and check where you went wrong:**

1. Below is my test data extension.

[image]

2. Below is the journey I have used to test:

[image]

3. I have used the below code:

> ```
> Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
> POST /interaction/v1/events
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
> ```

```
{
    "ContactKey": "ID601",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent Key",
    "Data": {
        "SubscriberKey":"ID601",
        "EmailAddress":"xyz@gmail.com",
        "FirstName":"Test",
        "LastName":"Test1"}
}
```

4. I have received an email after some minutes.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the details Naveen. My issue is solved and email is now sent. The actual issue which I think for me was that my underlying DE was based in triggered send template which should be not. This resolved the issue

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer Gautam. You can add it as a seperate answer and remove mine from the right answer. So that it helps someone if he/she faces the same problem. Am glad that your issue has been resolved :)